# Is there a way to prevent a "The requested session cannot be accepted. It may be locked by another receiver."

Tags: c#, azure, react-native, signalr

I have tryed so much but nothing seems to work in my use case.

I have an react/redux frontend setting up a signalR connection to my asp.net core server. After this, the frontend triggers a function called "startTesting". This function has a loop where every 4 seconds it sends an update to my frontend. The data inside the update comes from an Azure Message Session and needs to be FIFO. I'm using a singleton to get this data and pass it to the signalR hub where it is processed and send to the frontend. The singleton message processor code looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> ReceiveMessage(string imei, CancellationToken ct = default) 
{ 
    var receiver = await _sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(imei);

    try
    {
        if (!_processingSessions.TryAdd(imei, true))
        {
            throw new Exception("Session is already being processed");
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, ct);

        Message message = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

        if (message == null) return null;

        _logger.LogInformation("Message received: {Message}", message.Body);

        await receiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Service Bus Exception: {ExMessage}", e.Message);
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // _logger.LogInformation("Closing Message Session");
        _processingSessions.TryRemove(imei, out var result);
            imei, result);
        await receiver.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

This al works fine in a "happy flow". I start the connection, the test starts and then this is triggered. But as soon as a refresh on the signalR side happends, the old connection is disposed and the new connection is created this creates the error "The requested session cannot be accepted. It may be locked by another receiver.". Even do i say await receiver.closeAsync() inside the finally.

Can someone help me out here I can't get to figure this out. Btw: I already tried a ServiceBusSessionReceiver.

The ServiceBusSessionReceiver i tried:

```
//Constructor:
// _serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient.CreateClient("DeviceTestQueue");

//Message processor receiver:
// var receiver = await _serviceBusClient.AcceptSessionAsync(
//     _configuration.GetSection("DEVICETESTMSGQUEUE").Value,
//     imei, cancellationToken: ct
// );
```

I'm not sure if it's of any help but here is my signalR frontend code(I might did something wrong with session management):

```
import {
    HttpTransportType,
    HubConnectionBuilder,
    HubConnectionState,
    JsonHubProtocol,
    LogLevel
} from '@microsoft/signalr';
import * as types from "../actions/actionsTypes";

const baseUrl = process.env.SOCKET_URL + 'devicetests/ws';
const protocol = new JsonHubProtocol();

let connection = null;

export const initializeConnection = (imei) => async (dispatch) => {
    let url = `not relevant`;

    if (!connection) {
        console.log("Creating new DeviceTestSocket connection");

        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(
            url,
            {
                // accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken,
                transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling,
                logMessageContent: true,
                logger: LogLevel.Debug,
            })
            .withHubProtocol(protocol)
            .build();
    }

    await connection.start().then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to DeviceTestSocket");

        startTesting(imei);
    });


    await connection.on("SendTests", (message) => {
        console.log("SendTests Triggered");
        dispatch({
            type: types.INITIALIZE_TESTS,
            payload: {
                deviceTests: message
            }
        })
    });

    await connection.on("UpdateTest", (message) => {
        console.log("UpdateTest Triggered");
        dispatch({
            type: types.UPDATE_TEST,
            payload: {
                deviceTests: message
            }
        })
    });
}

export const startTesting = async (imei) => {
    if (isConnectionOpen) {
        await connection.invoke("StartTesting", imei, new Date());
    }
}

export const closeConnection = () => async (dispatch) => {
    if (isConnectionOpen) {
        connection.stop().then(() => {
            console.log("Disconnected from DeviceTestSocket");
        });

        dispatch({
            type: types.FINISH_TESTS,
            payload: {
                deviceTests: []
            }
        });
    }
}

export const isConnectionOpen = () => connection && connection.state === HubConnectionState.Connected;
```

Hope this helps!

******Edited******

After implementing the solution of Rick Montalvo it works better but after firm testing I keep getting the error.

I'll share my signalR code here as well which calls the "ReceiveMessage" function which i already shared. My SignalR code looks like this:

```
public class DeviceTestHub : Hub<IDeviceTestClient>
{
    private readonly ILogger<DeviceTestHub> _logger;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly IMessageProcessor _messageProcessor;
    private readonly IDeviceTestHandler _deviceTestHandler;
    private readonly TimeSpan _cacheExpirationTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;


    public DeviceTestHub(IDeviceTestHandler deviceTestHandler, IMemoryCache memoryCache,
        ILogger<DeviceTestHub> logger, IMessageProcessor messageProcessor)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
        _logger = logger;
        _messageProcessor = messageProcessor;
        _deviceTestHandler = deviceTestHandler;
        
        //Set cancellation token for 12 minutes to cancel the test if it takes longer than 12 minutes
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12));
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //Get IMEI from header
        var context = Context.GetHttpContext();

        //Try get imei from header
        if (!context!.Request.Query.TryGetValue("imei", out var imei)) return;

        _logger.LogInformation("Connection established for device: {imei}", imei);

        //Connect to hub
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();

        var savedTests = _cache.Get<List<SocketModel>>($"{MemoryCacheKeys.DeviceTest}-{imei}");

        if (savedTests != null)
        {
            //Send saved tests to device
            await Clients.Caller.SendTests(savedTests);

            return;
        }

        //Get socket tests
        var socketTests = await _deviceTestHandler.GetTests(imei);

        //Save socket tests that specific imei has to run in case of disconnection, refresh or other connection
        _cache.Set($"{MemoryCacheKeys.DeviceTest}-{imei}", socketTests, _cacheExpirationTime);


        //Send list with tests to frontend
        await Clients.Caller.SendTests(socketTests);

        //Remove possible old session imei's from cache
        await _messageProcessor.Dispose(imei);
    }

    public async Task StartTesting(string imei, DateTime startDate)
    {
        try
        {
            //Clear session before start testing
            await _messageProcessor.Dispose(imei);

            //Do the actual tests
            //Get raw message from Message Session, send it to the frontend but also pass it to the test handler
            var socketTests =
                _cache.Get<List<SocketModel>>($"{MemoryCacheKeys.DeviceTest}-{imei}")
                ?? await _deviceTestHandler.GetTests(imei);

            var messages = new List<RawMessageDTO>();

            while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if (socketTests.Any(x => x.State == State.NotStarted))
                {
                    //Loop through tests and return the first test that is not started yet and set it to loading
                    var test = _deviceTestHandler.SetTestActive(socketTests, _cts.Token);

                    //Send the changed test to frontend
                    if (test != null) await Clients.Caller.UpdateTest(test);
                }
                
                //Get raw message from Message Session
                var message = await _messageProcessor.ReceiveMessage(imei, _cts.Token);

                if (message.IsNullOrEmpty() && messages.IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000, _cts.Token);
                    continue;
                }

                if (!message.IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    var rawMsg = await _deviceTestHandler.ConvertMessageToRawMessage(message);

                    //Send raw message to frontend
                    await Clients.Caller.SendRawMessage(JsonSerializer.Serialize(rawMsg));

                    messages.Add(rawMsg);
                }

                var activeTest = socketTests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.State is State.Loading or State.Inprogress);

                if (activeTest is null) return;

                var executedTest = await _deviceTestHandler.ExecuteTest(imei, activeTest, messages, startDate);

                if (executedTest != null)
                {
                    //Send the changed test to frontend
                    await Clients.Caller.UpdateTest(executedTest);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendMessage($"Test took longer than 12 minutes and is cancelled for imei: {imei}");
            await _messageProcessor.Dispose(imei);
            await OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"");
            await _messageProcessor.Dispose(imei);
            await Clients.Caller.SendMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        
        //Get IMEI from header
        var context = Context.GetHttpContext();

        //Try get imei from header
        if (!context!.Request.Query.TryGetValue("imei", out var imei)) return;

        await _messageProcessor.Dispose(imei);

        if (exception != null)
            _logger.LogError("Error!");

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```